# Convert Json Array into CSV

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

I would like to convert an array of JSON into a CSV format. I would like the first line of the CSV to be the label of the data.

There is a sample of my array:

```
objArray = [
    {"idMachine": 195, "LabelStop": "No more piece", "LabelNC": "Default"},
    {"idMachine": 214, "LabelStop": "No more box", "LabelNC": "Default"}
]
```

And the result I want :

```
idMachine;LabelStop;LabelNC
195;No more piece;Default
214;No more box;Default
```

For the moment, my code looks like that :

```
convertToCSV(objArray) {
    var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
    var str = '';
        
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var line = '';

        for (var index in array[i]) {
            if (i == 0) {
                if (line != '') line += ';'
        
                line += index;
        
            } else {
                if (line != '') line += ';'
        
                line += array[i][index];
            }
        }
        str += line + '\r\n';
    }
    return str;
}
```

The problem is that the first line is the data labels but the first values are skipped. My CSV looks like that :

```
idMachine;LabelStop;LabelNC
214;No more box;Default
```

Comment: Of course the values of the first line are skipped - because you are adding the values only in the `else` branch, and with `if (i == 0)` being true for that first line, it never gets to adding the values.

Comment: @CBroe Yes but I don't know how I can correct my program..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently looping over the items in your array, and then the individual properties of each item - so you won’t be able to do it this exact way with `line +=`, because the data is not coming in the correct order for that.

Easiest if you just use an additional helper variable for the header line, and then prepend that to the rest of the output at the very end. The `else` simply gets removed, and the code you had in there executed in any case, not just when `i!=0` (so that you get the *data* from the first item as well, your if/else construct is what made that get “skipped” in the first place.)

```
function convertToCSV(objArray) {
    var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
    var str = '', header = '';
        
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var line = '';

        for (var index in array[i]) {
            if (i == 0) {
                if (header != '') {
                   header += ';'
                }
                header += index;
            }
            if (line != '') {
              line += ';'
            }
            line += array[i][index];
        }
        str += line + '\r\n';
    }
    return (header + '\r\n' + str);
}
```

Comment: Ok I understand what were wrong with my program. I tried your version and it works better. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
let objArray = [
    { "idMachine": 195, "LabelStop": "No more piece", "LabelNC": "Default" },
    { "idMachine": 214, "LabelStop": "No more box", "LabelNC": "Default" }
]

const header = Object.keys(objArray[0])
let csv = objArray.map(row => header.map(fieldName => JSON.stringify(row[fieldName])).join(';'))
csv.unshift(header.join(','))
csv = csv.join('\r\n')

console.log(csv);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have this error```objArray.map is not a function``` doesn't work.